# Python - Getting the wrong solution for Cholesky decomposition?

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to translate some pseudocode from matlab to a python script, but I'm having some trouble with getting the correct answer? Can someone help me identify where I messed up the translation?

The pseudocode I'm given in the one for Cholesky decomposition given in the Trefethan & Bau book is

[image]

This is done for an upper triangular matrix if i understand the description given correctly, but I think this should work for a general matrix too, no?

Anyway, I wrote the following code in python:

```
def is_SPD(A):
    if np.all(A == A.T):
        if np.all(la.eigvals(A) > 0):
            return True
    return False

def cholesky_decomp(A):
    #first check if matrix is symmetric and positive definite
    if is_SPD(A) == True:
        R = np.copy(A)
        for k in range (0, len(A)):
            for j in range (k+1, len(A)):
                R[j,j:] = R[j,j:] - (R[k,j:]*(R[k,j]/R[k,k]))
            R[k,k:] = R[k,k:]/sqrt(R[k,k])
        return R
    else:
        return print('Cholesky decomposition not applicable')
```

I'm working on a 4x4 matrix, and I've done the decomposition by the np.linalg method, and my answers are completely different.

I think this might? be because of my unfamiliarity with MATLAB and my lack of coding skills in general, but I'm not getting any correct answers at all and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm adding a sample matrix here that I'm using, and that this *shoulddd* be applicable to, and should give a proper Cholesky decomposition for, but I'm getting a completely incorrect answer.

Could someone please use this to help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

```
A = np.array([[16, -12, -12, -16], [-12, 25, 1, -4], [-12, 1, 17, 14], [-16, -4, 14, 57]])
```

my code gave me:

```
[[  4  -3  -3  -4]
 [-12   4  -2  -4]
 [-12   1   2  -3]
 [-16  -4  14   4]]
```

while the numpy Cholesky function gave me:

```
[[ 4.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-3.  4.  0.  0.]
 [-3. -2.  2.  0.]
 [-4. -4. -3.  4.]]
```

Comment: AHHH I'm sorry, was typing this in a hurry lol

Comment: Can you please help me identify what's making my code give me the wrong answer though? :/

Comment: Is the decomposition you are comparing against also Cholesky or is a general LU? In the latter case the two are different by a scaling by the diagonal.

Comment: No, no, I compared it to the numpy linalg Cholesky decomposition (which I also calculated by hand), and while the numpy one was the same as what I got, this one was giving me an incorrect answer, but I'm not entirely sure why. I'm going to edit my post and add the solutions/decompositions that I got from both methods to show the difference if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code correctly implements the stated algorithm, but note that the text says (*added emphasis*):

> The input matrix **A** represents the **superdiagonal half** of the *m*×*m* Hermitian positive definite matrix to be factored.

So you need to replace the input `A`,

```
[[ 16 -12 -12 -16]
 [-12  25   1  -4]
 [-12   1  17  14]
 [-16  -4  14  57]]
```

by `np.triu(A)`:

```
[[ 16 -12 -12 -16]
 [  0  25   1  -4]
 [  0   0  17  14]
 [  0   0   0  57]]
```

In addition (*notation slightly changed, where `'` means Hermitian transpose*),

> The output matrix **R** represents the **upper-triangular** factor for which **A** = **R**' **R**

So you get an upper-triangular **R**, whereas Numpy's `cholesky` function gives a lower-triangular result. Each of these results is just the Hermitian-transposed version of the other (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/232202/28285)).

Comment: OHHH okay, so they *don't* both work for the exact same matrix!! Also nice, I didn't know there was a function like np.triu, so that's definitely interesting to learn. But this is really helpful, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

L=numpy.linalg.cholesky(A)

A=np.dot(L,L.T.conj())

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).